# Accepting multiple inputs loop

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I've written a program in Java that does a series of calculations, basically a payroll program for four different types of employees. I'm having an issue trying to make it NOT exit after the input is completed.

For example: The user is asked how many employees are in the company. From there it should start asking what employee #1's type is (manager, hourly, etc...) then keep asking until the total employees are met, say for example 4. After each input it's okay for the employee's name and information to output.

Here's what I have thus far, which is an almost complete, working program. The only thing left is the part I described above.

Any resources to help me work out the solution are more valuable than rewriting my code.

Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class PayrollSwitch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // First input group
        int employeeType;               // 1-4 (Manager, Hourly, Commissioned, Pieceworker)
        int compSize;                   // Company size (4 - 10)
        int hoursWrkd;                  // Whole Number, no partial hours.
        String employeeName;            // Name of the Employee

        // Pay for each worker type
        double rateManagerWrkr = 800.00;// Fixed weekly salary
        double managerBonus = 750.00;   // $750.00 bonus for manager
        double rateHourWrkr;            // Hourly + overtime > 40 = 1.5 time hourly rate
        double hourOvertime = 1.5;      // If hoursWrkd > 40
        double hourOvertimeStore;       // Stores value
        double rateCommWrkr = 650.00;   // Fixed weekly salary
        double commBonus = 250.00;      // $250.00 bonus for commissioned worker

        double commWklySal;             // 5.7% time weekly salary (650.00 * 5.7)

        double ratePieceWrkr = 400.00;  // Fixed weekly salary

        // Deductions
        double medicalDues = 20.00;     // $20.00 per pay period
        double fedTax = 0.30;           // 30% of gross
        double socialSec = 0.05;        // 5% of gross
        double deductDues;
        double fedTaxFinal;
        double socialSecFinal;

        // Totals
        double managerGross;
        double managerNet;
        double hourGross;
        double hourNet;
        double commGross;
        double commNet;
        double pieceGross;
        double pieceNet;

        // Convert decimals to match ####.## place ($9999.99)
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####.##");

        String employeeTitle;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter an employee paycode (1-4): ");
        employeeType = input.nextInt();

        switch (employeeType)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                employeeTitle = "Manager";
                System.out.println("You selected manager!");
                System.out.print("What's your name? :");
                employeeName = input.next();

                System.out.print("Enter the amount of hours worked this week: ");
                hoursWrkd = input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Name: "             + employeeName);
                System.out.println("Title: "            + employeeTitle);
                System.out.println("Type: "             + employeeType);
                System.out.println("Hours worked: "     + hoursWrkd);

                managerGross = rateManagerWrkr + managerBonus;
                System.out.println("Gross pay: $"        + df.format(managerGross));
                System.out.println("Federal Tax: $"      + df.format(managerGross * fedTax));
                System.out.println("Social Security: $"  + df.format(managerGross * socialSec));
                System.out.println("Medical: $"          + df.format(medicalDues));

                fedTaxFinal = managerGross * fedTax;
                socialSecFinal = managerGross * socialSec;
                deductDues = (fedTaxFinal + socialSecFinal + medicalDues);
                managerNet = (managerGross - deductDues);
                System.out.println("Net pay: $"          + df.format(managerNet));
            }
            break;
            case 2:
            {
                employeeTitle = "Hourly";
                System.out.println("You selected hourly!");
                System.out.print("What's your name? :");
                employeeName = input.next();

                System.out.print("Enter the amount of hours worked this week: ");
                hoursWrkd = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter hourly rate: $");
                rateHourWrkr = input.nextDouble();

                hourGross = rateHourWrkr * hoursWrkd;

                System.out.println("Name: "             + employeeName);
                System.out.println("Title: "            + employeeTitle);
                System.out.println("Type: "             + employeeType);
                // Begin checking hours worked
                if (hoursWrkd > 40)
                {
                    hourOvertimeStore = (hoursWrkd - 40) * rateHourWrkr * hourOvertime;
                    System.out.println("Hours worked: "     + hoursWrkd);
                    System.out.println("Overtime hours: " + (hoursWrkd - 40));
                    System.out.println("Gross pay: $"        + df.format(hourGross + hourOvertimeStore));
                    System.out.println("Federal Tax: $"      + df.format(hourGross * fedTax));
                    System.out.println("Social Security: $"  + df.format(hourGross * socialSec));
                    System.out.println("Medical: $"          + df.format(medicalDues));
                    fedTaxFinal = hourGross * fedTax;
                    socialSecFinal = hourGross * socialSec;
                    deductDues = (fedTaxFinal + socialSecFinal + medicalDues);
                    hourNet = (hourGross - deductDues);

                    System.out.println("Net pay: $"          + df.format(hourNet));
                }
                else
                {
                    hourGross = hoursWrkd * rateHourWrkr;
                    hourOvertimeStore = 0;
                    System.out.println("Hours worked: "     + hoursWrkd);

                    System.out.println("Gross pay: $"        + df.format(hourGross + hourOvertimeStore));
                    System.out.println("Federal Tax: $"      + df.format(hourGross * fedTax));
                    System.out.println("Social Security: $"  + df.format(hourGross * socialSec));
                    System.out.println("Medical: $"          + df.format(medicalDues));

                    fedTaxFinal = hourGross * fedTax;
                    socialSecFinal = hourGross * socialSec;
                    deductDues = (fedTaxFinal + socialSecFinal + medicalDues);
                    hourNet = (hourGross - deductDues);
                    System.out.println("Net pay: "          + df.format(hourNet));
                }
            }
            break;
            case 3:
            {
                employeeTitle = "Commission";
                System.out.println("You selected commission!");
                System.out.print("What's your name? :");
                employeeName = input.next();

                System.out.print("Enter the amount of hours worked this week: ");
                hoursWrkd = input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Name: "             + employeeName);
                System.out.println("Title: "            + employeeTitle);
                System.out.println("Type: "             + employeeType);
                System.out.println("Hours worked: "     + hoursWrkd);


                commGross = rateCommWrkr + commBonus;
                commWklySal = (0.057 * rateCommWrkr);
                System.out.println("Commission made: $" + df.format(commWklySal));

                System.out.println("Gross pay: $"        + df.format(commWklySal + commGross));
                System.out.println("Federal Tax: $"      + df.format((commWklySal + commGross) * fedTax));
                System.out.println("Social Security: $"  + df.format((commWklySal + commGross) * socialSec));
                System.out.println("Medical: $"          + df.format(medicalDues));

                fedTaxFinal = (commWklySal + commGross) * fedTax;
                socialSecFinal = (commWklySal + commGross) * socialSec;
                deductDues = (fedTaxFinal + socialSecFinal + medicalDues);
                commNet = (commWklySal + commGross) - deductDues;
                System.out.println("Net pay: $"          + df.format(commNet));
            }
            break;
            case 4:
            {
                employeeTitle = "Pieceworker";
                System.out.println("You selected pieceworker!");
                System.out.print("What's your name? :");
                employeeName = input.next();

                System.out.print("Enter the amount of hours worked this week: ");
                hoursWrkd = input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Name: "             + employeeName);
                System.out.println("Title: "            + employeeTitle);
                System.out.println("Type: "             + employeeType);
                System.out.println("Hours worked: "     + hoursWrkd);

                pieceGross = ratePieceWrkr;
                System.out.println("Gross pay: $"        + df.format(pieceGross));
                System.out.println("Federal Tax: $"      + df.format(pieceGross * fedTax));
                System.out.println("Social Security: $"  + df.format(pieceGross * socialSec));
                System.out.println("Medical: $"          + df.format(medicalDues));

                pieceNet = pieceGross - fedTax - socialSec - medicalDues;
                System.out.println("Net pay: $"          + df.format(pieceNet));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'NOT exit after the input is completed' do you want to execute this in loop ??

Comment: Ask the user how many employees, take in that number, then use a for loop to iterate your code that many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not asking the "Number of Employees" from the User in your code.Hope this is what you want.

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // First input group
        int employeeType;               // 1-4 (Manager, Hourly, Commissioned, Pieceworker)
        int compSize;                   // Company size (4 - 10)
        int hoursWrkd;                  // Whole Number, no partial hours.
        String employeeName;            // Name of the Employee

        // Pay for each worker type
        double rateManagerWrkr = 800.00;// Fixed weekly salary
        double managerBonus = 750.00;   // $750.00 bonus for manager
        double rateHourWrkr;            // Hourly + overtime > 40 = 1.5 time hourly rate
        double hourOvertime = 1.5;      // If hoursWrkd > 40
        double hourOvertimeStore;       // Stores value
        double rateCommWrkr = 650.00;   // Fixed weekly salary
        double commBonus = 250.00;      // $250.00 bonus for commissioned worker

        double commWklySal;             // 5.7% time weekly salary (650.00 * 5.7)

        double ratePieceWrkr = 400.00;  // Fixed weekly salary

        // Deductions
        double medicalDues = 20.00;     // $20.00 per pay period
        double fedTax = 0.30;           // 30% of gross
        double socialSec = 0.05;        // 5% of gross
        double deductDues;
        double fedTaxFinal;
        double socialSecFinal;

        // Totals
        double managerGross;
        double managerNet;
        double hourGross;
        double hourNet;
        double commGross;
        double commNet;
        double pieceGross;
        double pieceNet;

        // Convert decimals to match ####.## place ($9999.99)
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####.##");

        String employeeTitle;
        int numberOfEmployees=0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.print("Enter the number of Employees in your company ");
        numberOfEmployees = input.nextInt();


        for(int i=0;i<numberOfEmployees;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Enter Information for Employee Number " + Integer.toString(i+1));
            System.out.print("Enter an employee paycode (1-4): ");
            employeeType = input.nextInt();

            switch (employeeType)
            {
            case 1:
            {
                employeeTitle = "Manager";
                System.out.println("You selected manager!");
                System.out.print("What's your name? :");
                employeeName = input.next();

                System.out.print("Enter the amount of hours worked this week: ");
                hoursWrkd = input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Name: "             + employeeName);
                System.out.println("Title: "            + employeeTitle);
                System.out.println("Type: "             + employeeType);
                System.out.println("Hours worked: "     + hoursWrkd);

                managerGross = rateManagerWrkr + managerBonus;
                System.out.println("Gross pay: $"        + df.format(managerGross));
                System.out.println("Federal Tax: $"      + df.format(managerGross * fedTax));
                System.out.println("Social Security: $"  + df.format(managerGross * socialSec));
                System.out.println("Medical: $"          + df.format(medicalDues));

                fedTaxFinal = managerGross * fedTax;
                socialSecFinal = managerGross * socialSec;
                deductDues = (fedTaxFinal + socialSecFinal + medicalDues);
                managerNet = (managerGross - deductDues);
                System.out.println("Net pay: $"          + df.format(managerNet));
            }
            break;
            case 2:
            {
                employeeTitle = "Hourly";
                System.out.println("You selected hourly!");
                System.out.print("What's your name? :");
                employeeName = input.next();

                System.out.print("Enter the amount of hours worked this week: ");
                hoursWrkd = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter hourly rate: $");
                rateHourWrkr = input.nextDouble();

                hourGross = rateHourWrkr * hoursWrkd;

                System.out.println("Name: "             + employeeName);
                System.out.println("Title: "            + employeeTitle);
                System.out.println("Type: "             + employeeType);
                // Begin checking hours worked
                if (hoursWrkd > 40)
                {
                    hourOvertimeStore = (hoursWrkd - 40) * rateHourWrkr * hourOvertime;
                    System.out.println("Hours worked: "     + hoursWrkd);
                    System.out.println("Overtime hours: " + (hoursWrkd - 40));
                    System.out.println("Gross pay: $"        + df.format(hourGross + hourOvertimeStore));
                    System.out.println("Federal Tax: $"      + df.format(hourGross * fedTax));
                    System.out.println("Social Security: $"  + df.format(hourGross * socialSec));
                    System.out.println("Medical: $"          + df.format(medicalDues));
                    fedTaxFinal = hourGross * fedTax;
                    socialSecFinal = hourGross * socialSec;
                    deductDues = (fedTaxFinal + socialSecFinal + medicalDues);
                    hourNet = (hourGross - deductDues);

                    System.out.println("Net pay: $"          + df.format(hourNet));
                }
                else
                {
                    hourGross = hoursWrkd * rateHourWrkr;
                    hourOvertimeStore = 0;
                    System.out.println("Hours worked: "     + hoursWrkd);

                    System.out.println("Gross pay: $"        + df.format(hourGross + hourOvertimeStore));
                    System.out.println("Federal Tax: $"      + df.format(hourGross * fedTax));
                    System.out.println("Social Security: $"  + df.format(hourGross * socialSec));
                    System.out.println("Medical: $"          + df.format(medicalDues));

                    fedTaxFinal = hourGross * fedTax;
                    socialSecFinal = hourGross * socialSec;
                    deductDues = (fedTaxFinal + socialSecFinal + medicalDues);
                    hourNet = (hourGross - deductDues);
                    System.out.println("Net pay: "          + df.format(hourNet));
                }
            }
            break;
            case 3:
            {
                employeeTitle = "Commission";
                System.out.println("You selected commission!");
                System.out.print("What's your name? :");
                employeeName = input.next();

                System.out.print("Enter the amount of hours worked this week: ");
                hoursWrkd = input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Name: "             + employeeName);
                System.out.println("Title: "            + employeeTitle);
                System.out.println("Type: "             + employeeType);
                System.out.println("Hours worked: "     + hoursWrkd);


                commGross = rateCommWrkr + commBonus;
                commWklySal = (0.057 * rateCommWrkr);
                System.out.println("Commission made: $" + df.format(commWklySal));

                System.out.println("Gross pay: $"        + df.format(commWklySal + commGross));
                System.out.println("Federal Tax: $"      + df.format((commWklySal + commGross) * fedTax));
                System.out.println("Social Security: $"  + df.format((commWklySal + commGross) * socialSec));
                System.out.println("Medical: $"          + df.format(medicalDues));

                fedTaxFinal = (commWklySal + commGross) * fedTax;
                socialSecFinal = (commWklySal + commGross) * socialSec;
                deductDues = (fedTaxFinal + socialSecFinal + medicalDues);
                commNet = (commWklySal + commGross) - deductDues;
                System.out.println("Net pay: $"          + df.format(commNet));
            }
            break;
            case 4:
            {
                employeeTitle = "Pieceworker";
                System.out.println("You selected pieceworker!");
                System.out.print("What's your name? :");
                employeeName = input.next();

                System.out.print("Enter the amount of hours worked this week: ");
                hoursWrkd = input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Name: "             + employeeName);
                System.out.println("Title: "            + employeeTitle);
                System.out.println("Type: "             + employeeType);
                System.out.println("Hours worked: "     + hoursWrkd);

                pieceGross = ratePieceWrkr;
                System.out.println("Gross pay: $"        + df.format(pieceGross));
                System.out.println("Federal Tax: $"      + df.format(pieceGross * fedTax));
                System.out.println("Social Security: $"  + df.format(pieceGross * socialSec));
                System.out.println("Medical: $"          + df.format(medicalDues));

                pieceNet = pieceGross - fedTax - socialSec - medicalDues;
                System.out.println("Net pay: $"          + df.format(pieceNet));
            }
            break;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Thank you for using this Application");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you need a [loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html), I suggest you use a `do-while` loop - that is, something like,

```
boolean stop = false;
do {
  // as before
  // set stop to true to end the loop.
} while (!stop);
```

Comment: I will test this solution, however the answer above is working and correct. Thank you for your input and help.